# MathQuill Editable Math Fields on textarea

Tags: javascript, html, mathquill

I'm trying to make something like [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com) but with MathQuill so you can easily type text and math. But i've run into a few problems.

1. A single editable math field (`span`) where you can type math and switch to text mode with a keyboard shortcut `Shfit + T`. Javascript will capture the keypress event and execute `mathField.cmd('\\text');`. You can then use the arrow keys to move in and out of text and math mode. Seems perfect, unfortunately this acts like a "input" and not a "textarea" so you can't press enter and jump to a new line. And it doesn't seem like changing from `span` to `textarea` just breaks everything.
2. So seeing the first method didn't work out, I added a content editable div and you can switch to math mode with a keyboard shortcut `Shift + E`. Javascript will capture the keypress event and insert the html `<span id="stdin"></span>` into the div and run MathQuill on it. Unfortunately this is extremely buggy when it comes to moving the cursor around and just annoying to deal with. Also i'm not sure if setting multiple mathquill fields is possible (I haven't tried it yet)

I want to stick with the first method since it's simple and works just the way I want it to. But I don't know how to change it from the "input" style to "textarea".
Does anyone know how to do this?